# Bazel build failed using `rust_binary`

Tags: rust, bazel-rules

I am using Bazel 7.0 to build my rust project, but when I tried to run `bazel build`, Bazel compiled about as following:

```
ERROR: /data/cbs/projects/cron/data_plane/BUILD:5:12: While resolving toolchains for target //data_plane:scheduled (7f21caa): invalid registered toolchain '@bazel_skylib//toolchains/unittest:bash_toolchain': no such package '@@bazel_skylib//toolchains/unittest': BUILD file not found in directory 'toolchains/unittest' of external repository @@bazel_skylib. Add a BUILD file to a directory to mark it as a package.
```

But the `BUILD` under `bazel_skylib/toolchains/unittest` is existed, how can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a minimal example project reproducing the problem.